# The same session information for peer users on two different WordPress servers

Tags: users, login, rest-api, cookies, authentication

The MultiSite feature of WordPress is very nice. But for different WordPress installations on different servers, I need something like this.

When a user logs on site `(A)`, if the same user has a duplicate on site `(B)`, the session information is transferred to the server `(B)` (Internet Browser Cookie) when they open site `(B)`.

Is this possible?

---

If such a thing is not possible,

Is it possible to activate a user's session via the internet browser where the request is made with WordPress Rest API?

---

Let's say my 2nd proposal is not possible.
So is it possible to get the list of users with active sessions via the wp-rest API?

Comment: This sounds like you want cross-domain cookies, but you'll also need a lot of other things as those installs won't share the same user table. What you ask for is non-trivial and a lot of work. Expect major problems to occur. Instead, you could implement federated login, like when you log in with google, but using your own site as the authentication provider instead so that they maintain a single account

Comment: Also, all your proposals introduce major security vulnerabilities